# python не видит модуль marshmallow_dataclass

Tags: python, pip, библиотеки

Всем привет! Я еще новичок в Python и не совсем пойму с чем может быть связана ошибка.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vl/PycharmProjects/asinchronTgBot/run_bot.py", line 5, in <module>
    from bot.base import Bot
  File "/Users/vl/PycharmProjects/asinchronTgBot/bot/base.py", line 3, in <module>
    from bot.poller import Poller
  File "/Users/vl/PycharmProjects/asinchronTgBot/bot/poller.py", line 5, in <module>
    from clients.tg import TgClient
  File "/Users/vl/PycharmProjects/asinchronTgBot/clients/tg/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .dcs import *
  File "/Users/vl/PycharmProjects/asinchronTgBot/clients/tg/dcs.py", line 4, in <module>
    from marshmallow_dataclass import dataclass
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'marshmallow_dataclass'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Ошибка возникает в этой строчке

```
from marshmallow_dataclass import dataclass
```

Я уже попробовал установить модуль через `pip` и настройки PyCharm. Однако Python все равно не видит его.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]